# Your connection is not private (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt, certbot

URL : https://vishnubathala.com/

```
**Error**
Subject: www.example.com
Issuer: www.example.com
Expires on: Aug 3, 2027
Current date: Nov 9, 2017
PEM encoded chain:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I followed the installation steps from the the certbot for ubuntu 14.04 version
but i am not sure what happen to the server i am getting this error how can i fix this error?

I am not sure whether my configuration is properly went through i want to configure it without any error please help me to fix this

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=vishnubathala.com looks like OP's sorted it out.

Answer (score 7):

The certificate that the site is using is self-signed - it is not a Letsencrypt certificate. Try checking the path to the SSL certificate and private key in your web server configuration. Which certificate is it pointing to?

Does the server need restarting to load the configuration file?

Has the letsencrypt certificate been installed successfully? The certificate that you posted in the question is the self-signed one.

Checking these would be a good start.

Comment: This server is running on aws i have deleted the whole instance and created new instance but still i am getting the same error i am not sure why?

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with the instance itself. You're using _Certbot_ incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

Your certificate has the wrong name listed. Using Chrome's Dev Tools, I see the following information on your site:

[image]

The certificate should be created with your server's name, not `www.example.com`.

Comment: But while configuring the cert-bot i have given the my domain name but not sure how it changed to www.example.com any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Issue a new certificate with the proper domain name.